# How to apply a function several times?

Tags: python

1. For given function (with one parameter, parameter type and return value type are equal) generate another function that applies original fuction multiple times.
   Example:

   ```
    from math import sin
    f1 = fn(lambda x: "sin(%s)" % x, 5)
    f2 = fn(lambda x: sin(x), 5)
    print("%s = %f" % (f1("1"), f2(1)))
    >>sin(sin(sin(sin(sin(1))))) = 0.587181
    print("%s = %f" % (f1("2"), f2(2)))
    >>sin(sin(sin(sin(sin(2))))) = 0.606464
    print(fn(lambda x: sin(x), 0)(1000))
    >> 1000
   ```

Function signature: def fn (f, n)

2. Using 'fn' (see first part of the task) generate function that calculates golden ratio approximation.
   final formula:

1 + 1 / (1 + 1 / (1 + 1 / (...)))
some results:

```
golden_ratio(0) = 1
golden_ratio(1) = 2
golden_ratio(2) = 1.5
golden_ratio(100) = 1.6180...
```

Function signature: def golden_ratio (n), where 'n' is number of invocations (and number of terms in continued fraction)

That's what I did, the golden ratio calculates everything well. But with the first part of the task, something is wrong, as in the example ...

first function fn which will apply a similar function a given number of times

second function - golden ratio which should use fn to calculate

code:

```
n = 100
def golden_ratio(f,n):
    def wrap(*arg):
        for _ in range(n+1):
            arg = f(*arg)
        return arg
    return wrap
 
def fib(q, w):
    q, w = w, q + w
    return q, w
 
f3 = golden_ratio(fib, n)
q, w = f3(0, 1)
# gold section
print(w / q)
```

it is executed, but not quite correctly, as in the example

Comment: Where is your definition of `fn`?

Comment: You can use recursivity to solve this.

Comment: That's why I ask, because I don’t know how to make the first part, where the function applies the original several times. Because the golden ratio itself is calculated well.

Comment: Right, but you should show an attempt of solving it. That way we can also understand where exactly your lack of understanding is.

Comment: Not sure why you are using `*arg` (allow for variable number of parameters) - it will work but by definition `f` takes only one parameter here.

Comment: @Bokan23 check my answer. It is iterative and I get the good result

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this:

```
def fn(f, n):
    r = 1/2
    for i in range(n):
        r = f(r)
    return r
    
    f = lambda x: 1+(1/x)

fn(f, 20)   # answer: 1.6180339789779863
```

Comment: You have just to change the definition of the function `f`

Comment: your question is not very clear, I don't know what you want to do exactly

Answer (score 0):

If you want a general function which can apply any type of function.

```
from math import sin

def fn(f, n):
    def wrap(*arg):
        for _ in range(n):
            if isinstance(arg, tuple):
                arg = f(*arg)  
            else:
                arg = f(arg) 
        return arg
    return wrap

f1 = fn(sin, 5)
f1(1)


def fib(q, w):
    q, w = w, q + w
    return q, w

f2 = fn(fib, 100)
q, w = f2(0, 1)
print(w/q)
```

Golden ratio

```
def golden_ratio(n):
    f = fn(fib, n+1)
    q, w = f(0, 1)
    return w/q

print(golden_ratio(0))
print(golden_ratio(1))
print(golden_ratio(2))
print(golden_ratio(100))
```

Output

```
1.0
2.0
1.5
1.618033988749895
```

Use Lambda

```
def golden_ratio(n):
    f = fn(lambda x, y: (y, x+y), n+1)
    q, w = f(0, 1)
    return w/q
```

Or

```
def golden_ratio(n):
    f = fn(lambda x: 1 + (1/x) if x != 0 else 1, n+1)
    return f(0)
```

Comment: This is not at all. First part should work with the sin example(

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want a general function which can  accept a function and calls that function many times.

Comment: returns tuple here

Comment: Code above handles both single value and tuple.

Comment: But is it possible to get rid of the fib() and replace it with a lambda?